# Difference between !foo and typeof foo === "undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What's the difference between this:

```
if(!foo) {
  ...
}
```

And this:

```
if(typeof foo === "undefined") {
  ...
}
```

I've seen some code which attempts to treat these two statements as though they're identical, but I've run into problems when doing so. I've been doing something like this with AngularJS:

```
var property = {
  value: $scope.foo //$scope.foo may or may not have been defined above, depending on contexts
  ...
};

func(property);

function func (property) {
  if(!property.value) {
  //This doesn't get executed, even if $scope.foo was never defined
  }
}
```

It seems to me that `(!foo)` !== `(typeof foo === "undefined")`

Is this correct?

Comment: Here is a post that can be useful to understand usage of ===   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example where they are not identical:

```
var foo = false;

if(!foo) {
    alert('!foo');
}

if(typeof foo === "undefined") {
    alert('undefined');
}
```

Only the first condition will be satisfied.